# How do I add a sticker to a line in emacs?

Tags: buffers

I'd like to add a sticker(marker) to a line in the buffer. I wanna do this because I want to mark places which I should not forgive to change during some refactoring process. I want these markers to be seen by me, for example, like gitgutter shows `git diff`, by adding `+`, `-` to the line start. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "sticker".

Comment: @Dan Well. A visual marker (for example, like git gutter marks the lines `+` `-` `~` in the git log) which sticks to a line in the source file and when you change the lines it still stays there. For example, if you place such a mark to line 10 and then remove first 5 lines of files, the marker will be at 5th line.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it. A (wild) guess is that (1) by "sticker" you mean a marker of some sort and (2) by "forgive" you mean forget. If so, look into `C-SPC` (setting the mark) and bookmarks (persistent markers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Emacs markers to "remember" places in a buffer and return to them. For that, `C-SPC` sets the mark and `C-u C-SPC` to move to the last position of the mark. See the Emacs manual, node [Mark Ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html).
2. For persistent "marks" you can use bookmarks. `C-x r m` sets a bookmark. You can then use `C-x r b` to jump to a bookmark (you are prompted for the name). You can also use `C-x r l` to get a list of your bookmarks and navigate to any of them. See the Emacs manual, node [Bookmarks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html).

The Emacs manual is your friend. Get to it using `C-h r`. In the manual, use `i` to find indexed information.

If you want to have a visual indication of bookmark locations then you can use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). It gives you various ways to [highlight bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#HighlightingBookmarkLocations), including using a mark in the window fringe for that.